# Export output of git status to html?

Tags: html, git, export

I'm interested to export "git status" output to some colorized html for git tutorial.

I found lot of stackoverflow discussions about `git log`, or `git diff` outputs customization on terminal, but anything about git status html export.

Do you know some tools to do that ?

**Update 1 :**

Probably using something like jc, which produce json based on any bash command was a first path to follow : https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc

Comment: try `git status --porcelain`

Comment: try https://pypi.org/project/ansi2html/